# Make form visible on all virtual desktops

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am creating a small call application so when the user does not have a note a window appears and informs you that it is necessary to have an activity pointed to to do, but this window should be seen by all virtual desktops that the user owns.

I found two posts here in SO, but they only tell you how to change the default behaviors of workspaces like go left, right, create, remove, and transfer items between them.

These are the posts:

- [API for Windows 10 virtual desktops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801402/api-for-windows-10-virtual-desktops)
- [Altering Win10 virtual desktop behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416843/altering-win10-virtual-desktop-behavior)

But as I said, I need the window to be visible in all work areas. I also saw that natively windows has an option when you press Alt + Tab and right click on the window you want, you have the option to keep it open in all workspaces. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/963858/possible-to-keep-a-window-in-all-virtual-desktops)

So how do I keep my application written in C # with windows forms open on all desktops?

Examples:

Here is the first desktop opening visual studio.
[image: Desktop 1]
However, when I change the desktop, the application remains in the foreground.
[image: Desktop 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548454/perisistant-window-across-multiple-windows-10-virtual-desktops

Comment: No, it's using WPF with other conditions, it was one of the POST's I've seen, however, if you read my POST I'm using Windows Forms which is different and what's more, I quoted the same repository.

Comment: I don't suppose there's any chance you ever figured this out and would be willing to post it as an answer?

Comment: In fact I ended up finding out after all ... But it was a long time after this post, I will look here for the repository and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished most easily by adding a value your to WS_EX_STYLES enum with the value of `0x00080080`. and using that style like I have below.I was able to get this enum with an Autohotkey script "checkstyles" available [here](http://www.computoredge.com/AutoHotkey/Free_AutoHotkey_Scripts_and_Apps_for_Learning_and_Generating_Ideas.html#CheckStyles) and checking the style of the vs 2019 splash screen.

```
IntPtr hwnd = WinAPI.CreateWindowEx2(
    0,
    WinAPI.RegisterClassEx2(ref wndClass),
    null,
    Win32Enums.WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
    ,
    -5, //x
    0 - WinAPI.GetSystemMetrics(Win32Enums.SystemMetric.SM_CYCAPTION) - 7, //y
    ScreenInfo.GetDisplays().MaxWidth  + 10, //width
    ScreenInfo.GetDisplays().MaxHeight + WinAPI.GetSystemMetrics(Win32Enums.SystemMetric.SM_CYCAPTION) + 15, //height
    IntPtr.Zero,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    wndClass.hInstance,
    IntPtr.Zero);


var ExStyle = WinAPI.GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, (IntPtr)Win32Enums.GWL.GWL_EXSTYLE);
WinAPI.SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, Win32Enums.GWL.GWL_EXSTYLE, (IntPtr)((int)ExStyle | (int)Win32Enums.WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_VisualStudioEmulation));
```