# How to stop a user from switching Desktops

Tags: c#, windows

So I want to create a program that stops the user (Only me, this isn't a virus) from moving away from it at all. Now I can already keep a window in Focus and covering the full screen but if someone has multiple Desktops opened they can switch to another one, open Task Manager and get rid of the program which is what I'm trying to avoid. (Trust me, it isn't a virus)

Now I've tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33572224/8517948) and copying it into my WPF Window's Constructor but it does literally nothing whether I use Windows + Tab or Ctrl + Windows + Arrow Keys to switch Desktops.

How would I best go about keeping that window on the screen no matter what happens?

Comment: Take a look at [Kiosk Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app). I imagine you're trying to do something like that.

Comment: Internet kiosks etc often do this by removing keys from the keyboard, so there literally isn’t a way to press Ctrl-alt-del for example